# chrome temporary storage is not reset

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, chromium

After look up of [Storage](https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage) I want to try to reset the temporary storage for testing purposes.

```
window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(webkitStorageInfo.TEMPORARY, 5*1024*1024,  
    function( bytes ) {
        console.log( "Quota is available: " + bytes );
    },
    function( e ) {
        console.log( "Error allocating quota: " + e );
    }); 

window.webkitStorageInfo.queryUsageAndQuota(webkitStorageInfo.TEMPORARY, 
    //the type can be either TEMPORARY or PERSISTENT
    function(used, remaining) {
        console.log("Used quota: " + used + ", current quota: " + remaining);
    }, function(e) {
         console.log('Error', e); 
    });
```

The requestQuota() set the temporary storage size and the queryUsageAndQuota() tell me what is the current quota. However when I look at the console log in the chrome browser although the new quota is set, it is not reflected by the `queryUsageAndQuota()`. I got something look like:

```
Quota is available: 5242880
Used quota: 0, current quota: 214748364
```

even though I expected what is avaliable and the current quota to be the same. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare these two Outputs

## Code 1

```
window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(webkitStorageInfo.TEMPORARY, 
             5188955171*1024*1024,  
    function( bytes ) {
        console.log( "Quota is available: " + bytes );
    },
    function( e ) {
        console.log( "Error allocating quota: " + e );
    }); 

window.webkitStorageInfo.queryUsageAndQuota(webkitStorageInfo.TEMPORARY, 
    //the type can be either TEMPORARY or PERSISTENT
    function(used, remaining) {
        console.log("Used quota: " + used + ", current quota: " + remaining);
    }, function(e) {
         console.log('Error', e); 
    });
```

## Output 1

```
Quota is available: 5188982205
Used quota: 492, current quota: 5188982205
```

## Code 2

```
window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(webkitStorageInfo.TEMPORARY, 5*1024*1024,  
    function( bytes ) {
        console.log( "Quota is available: " + bytes );
    },
    function( e ) {
        console.log( "Error allocating quota: " + e );
    }); 
window.webkitStorageInfo.queryUsageAndQuota(webkitStorageInfo.TEMPORARY, 
    //the type can be either TEMPORARY or PERSISTENT
    function(used, remaining) {
        console.log("Used quota: " + used + ", current quota: " + remaining);
    }, function(e) {
         console.log('Error', e); 
    });
```

## Output 2

```
Quota is available: 5242880
Used quota: 0, current quota: 214748364
```

In your case you have requested for a minor quota `5242880` which is already available and less than available amount, so it returns a `successCallback` with quota requested for! Reset the quota by requesting large number!

[window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota](https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage#requestQuota) is used for asking more storage **than available**, how ever Chrome automatically gives your app temporary storage, so you do not need to request allocation **( Maximum 20% of the shared pool)**

## References

- [Storage](https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage)

Comment: +1 This makes sense, but I would personally say it's more useful to get the actual quota back, rather than simply the passed number.

Comment: @pimvdb: Hmm i have a different view, the logical flow should be 1) first get actual quota using `queryUsageAndQuota` and then 2) request additional quota using `requestQuota`, by checking range of his request; How ever i see no harm if a user requests for a minor quota than available and system returning the value he requested for!

Comment: @Sudarshan the point of my testing is try to set the quota to be less than what is already exist(not more). So I guess in that regard it is impossible at this point?

Comment: @user1655072:Yes, there is no API to **modify**  quota to less than what is available